# Is there a way to make cvxpy timeout

Tags: python, cvxpy, integer-programming

I'm using cvxpy to solve an integer programming problem.  For feasible solutions, the .solve() method for cvxpy returns in a few tenths of a second.  For infeasible solutions, it can take 30+ seconds for cvxpy to return "infeasible".    Questions:

1) Is there a way to pass a timeout value to the solve() method?  If no, what is the recommended way to call cvxpy from a python program where I don't want to wait indefinitely?
2) Is it typical that cvxpy will take 30+ seconds to return infeasible?

Comment: If your `cvxpy` code is relatively contained, you could move it to s subprocess via `multiprocessing.Process`. Use its `.join` and `.terminate` methods to control timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is dependent on the solver you are using. [This page](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#setting-solver-options) has a a summary of options for different solvers.

You can see that CBC (Coin-or branch and cut) has a `maximumSeconds` option, but most solvers don't have a similar option.

However, most solvers allow you to specify a maximum number of iterations, which in practice will allow you some control to bound the computational time required for the solver to halt.

Comment: Thank you.  This worked great.  I've changed my code to the code below and it works perfectly now.


problem.solve(solver=cp.ECOS_BB, mi_max_iters=5)